# Reduction to Hessenberg-Triangular Form

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to reduce the following pair of matrices into Hessenberg-Triangular form where A is upper hessenberg and B is upper triangular.

A =\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 3 & 3
\end{array}

B =\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}

I have already found a Givens rotation matrix

Q =\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.7071 & 0.7071 \\
0 & -0.7071 & 0.7071
\end{array}

such that

A_new = Q*A =\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1.4142 & 4.2426 & 4.9497 \\
0 & 0 & -0.7071
\end{array}

B_new = Q*B =\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0.7071 & 2.8284 \\
0 & -0.7071 & 0
\end{array}

The next step is to find another rotation matrix Z and apply it to the right side of the updated matrices in order to return B into upper triangular form while also not destroying the zero created in the new A matrix (A_final = A_new*Z, B_final = B_new*Z). How do I go about finding this Z matrix?

Comment: Essentially, how do I apply/find a Given's rotation for B from the right side as opposed to the left?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anybody that is curious it still uses a Given's rotation and all you do is switch up the x vector in 
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
c & s\\
-s & c\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_1 \\
x_2 \end{array} \right) = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
* \\
0 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

so that instead of moving it from the bottom left corner on up to create zeros (as used for matrix A), it is moved from the bottom left corner on over to the right to create zeros in B when applied to the right side as previously stated. Then the process is repeated for the next column/row.